# URGENT MATTER - reopening of question

Tags: discussion

My question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262427/spawning-a-vw-beetle was closed. I dont want to speculate on reasons, as none where given. I here give close-voters a chance to explain themselves. If no reason is given, then reopening must ensue.

I find this an abuse of the system to close good questions for abusive reasons, can the users in question get banned?

I note that this is the same 5 users who closed my other question, which have a personal vendetta against me, can something be done about it?

Comment: It would indeed be an abuse of the system to close good questions for abusive reasons. However, I see neither a good question or an abusive reason anywhere here. Stop wasting our time and start asking better questions.

Comment: Loffen, five is a rather high number, a significant fraction of the active users who take care of similar work, and for a user like you whose reputation is 281, it sounds a bit comical to talk about the "personal vendetta" by 5 important users. Do you understand that 281 means that you're basically an unknown user? The question about VW Beatle sounded almost deliberately stupid - why Volkswagen? - and it was closed with the comment "it's not clear what you're asking". People could talk about quantum fluctuations except that they would run a risk that you say that they're not answering about VW

Answer (score 6):

There is no onus on site members to justify their actions.

I will generally try and provide a helpful comment if I have voted to close and if I think the question was asked in good faith. For example when I have voted to close on the grounds that a question is unclear I will often add a comment explaining what I think the problem is and how the question could be improved.

But I am not required to do this, and sometimes I don't leave a comment because I don't think it would help. The fact I have decided not to leave a comment is not grounds for cancelling my close vote and reopening the question.

If we take the question you link as an example, I would have voted to close as unclear because the question is simply unanswerable. There is no accepted mathematical model to describe the formation or otherwise of Boltzmann brains. The handwaving argument is generally that vacuum fluctuations create random collections of matter that have a small but non-zero probability of forming a brain (or in this case a VW Beetle). But the precise mechanisms involved are unclear and [as the Wikipedia article describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain#Proposed_resolutions) there are physicists who think the whole idea is misconceived.

The only way to answer your question would be to review the current models for Boltzmann brain formation, explain which model we are using then do a long and tedious calculation to end up with a number. This type of answer is too long to be suitable for this site, and in any case it would require a heroic effort to write. It is on these grounds that I would vote to close (as unclear) and I believe those who did vote feel the same way. Your question would need to be a lot more precise before it could be answered i.e. state what assumptions you're making. Alternatively you could ask about how the Boltzmann brain calculation would be done and what assumptions are necessary, though I think you'd need to show some evidence you had attempted to research this yourself.

A final point that needs to be mentioned is that this site operates on good will. No-one here has to answer a question and no-one here receives any material reward for doing so. We take the often considerable trouble to answer questions out of a desire to help and because it's nice when we are thanked for providing an answer. Taking a confrontational attitude will simply deter the site members from providing answers or even helpful comments.

Comment: I just need a rough estimate, u r free to use assumptions